# Parsing JSON Lines with Alamofire/Codable

Tags: ios, json, swift

Is it possible to parse JSON lines with Alamofire and codable?

Here is my code right now.

```
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString {(response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print ("response is \(value)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print ("error is \(error)")
            }
        }
```

This prints all the JSON lines as a string but I want to serialize the response as an array of JSON. How would I do that? The problem with JSON lines is that it returns each set of json on a separate line so it is not familiar to alamofire.

Here is what I tried as if this was traditional JSON which obviously it is not so this did not work:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {(response) in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        print ("response is \(value)")             
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970          
        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value)

        do {
            let logs = try decoder.decode([Logs].self, from: data)
            completion(logs)
        } catch let error {
            print ("error parsing get logs: \(error)")
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        print ("failed get logs: \(error) ** \(response.result.value ?? "")")
    }
}
```

For anybody unfamiliar with json lines here is the official format info: http://jsonlines.org

```
{"_logtype":"syslogline","_ingester":"agent","_ip":"40.121.203.183","pid":5573,"program":"docker","_host":"k8s-master-5A226838-0","logsource":"k8s-master-5A226838-0","_app":"syslog","_file":"/var/log/syslog","_line":"docker[5573]: I0411 00:18:39.644199    6124 conversion.go:134] failed to handle multiple devices for container. Skipping Filesystem stats","_ts":1491869920198,"timestamp":"2017-04-11T00:18:39.000Z","_id":"804760774821019649"}
{"_logtype":"syslogline","_ingester":"agent","_ip":"40.121.203.183","pid":5573,"program":"docker","_host":"k8s-master-5A226838-0","logsource":"k8s-master-5A226838-0","_app":"syslog","_file":"/var/log/syslog","_line":"docker[5573]: I0411 00:18:39.644167    6124 conversion.go:134] failed to handle multiple devices for container. Skipping Filesystem stats","_ts":1491869920198,"timestamp":"2017-04-11T00:18:39.000Z","_id":"804760774821019648"}
{"_logtype":"syslogline","_ingester":"agent","_ip":"40.121.203.183","pid":5573,"program":"docker","_host":"k8s-master-5A226838-0","logsource":"k8s-master-5A226838-0","_app":"syslog","_file":"/var/log/syslog","_line":"docker[5573]: I0411 00:18:37.053730    6124 operation_executor.go:917] MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume \"kubernetes.io/secret/6f322c04-e1d2-11e6-bca0-000d3a111245-default-token-swb07\" (spec.Name: \"default-token-swb07\") pod \"6f322c04-e1d2-11e6-bca0-000d3a111245\" (UID: \"6f322c04-e1d2-11e6-bca0-000d3a111245\").","_ts":1491869917193,"timestamp":"2017-04-11T00:18:37.000Z","_id":"804760762212941824"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of writing custom DataSerializer in Alamofire that you could use for decoding your Decodable object.

I am using an example from random posts json url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Here is an example of **Post** class and custom serializer class **PostDataSerializer**.

```
struct Post: Decodable {
    let userId: Int
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let body: String
}


struct PostDataSerializer: DataResponseSerializerProtocol {

    enum PostDataSerializerError: Error {
        case InvalidData
    }

    var serializeResponse: (URLRequest?, HTTPURLResponse?, Data?, Error?) -> Result<[Post]> {
        return { request, response, data, error in

            if let error = error {
                return .failure(error)

            }

            guard let data = data else {
                return .failure(PostDataSerializerError.InvalidData)
            }

            do {
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let posts = try jsonDecoder.decode([Post].self, from: data)
                return .success(posts)
            } catch {
                return .failure(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could simply hook this upto your Alamofire client which sends request to remote url like so,

```
let request = Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")

let postDataSerializer = PostDataSerializer()

request.response(responseSerializer: postDataSerializer) { response in
    print(response)
}
```

You could also do additional error checking for the error and http response code in serializeResponse getter of the custom serializer.

For you json line, it seems that each json object is separated with new line character in so called json line format. You could simply split the line with new line characters and decode each line to Log.

Here is Log class I created.

```
struct Log: Decodable {
    let logType: String
    let ingester: String
    let ip: String
    let pid: Int
    let host: String
    let logsource: String
    let app: String
    let file: String
    let line: String
    let ts: Float64
    let timestamp: String
    let id: String


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case logType = "_logtype"
        case ingester = "_ingester"
        case ip = "_ip"
        case pid
        case host = "_host"
        case logsource
        case app = "_app"
        case file = "_file"
        case line = "_line"
        case ts = "_ts"
        case timestamp
        case id = "_id"

    }
}
```

And custom log serializer that you could use with your Alamofire.  I have not handled error in the following serializer, I hope you can do it.

```
struct LogDataSerializer: DataResponseSerializerProtocol {

    enum LogDataSerializerError: Error {
        case InvalidData
    }

    var serializeResponse: (URLRequest?, HTTPURLResponse?, Data?, Error?) -> Result<[Post]> {
        return { request, response, data, error in

            if let error = error {
                return .failure(error)

            }

            guard let data = data else {
                return .failure(LogDataSerializerError.InvalidData)
            }

            do {
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

                let allLogs = string.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
                    .filter { $0 != "" }
                    .map { jsonLine -> Log? in
                        guard let data = jsonLine.data(using: .utf8) else {
                            return nil
                        }
                        return try? jsonDecoder.decode(Log.self, from: data)
                    }.flatMap { $0 }
                return .success(allLogs)
            } catch {
                return .failure(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks but this won't work for our use case. It does not handle JSON lines at all. it is just a normal serialize for an array of Post. That is not what I am looking for. This is a duplicate of the code that is in my question just written as a response serializer

Comment: Where did you get this json line from ? Is there any url where I could see the json and try it out myself ?

Comment: yes of course! here is a sample set of data and the docs for the API: https://docs.logdna.com/docs/v1-export-api

Comment: JSON line simply is a json in which each json object is separated with new line, see my edits above for custom serializer for json line for that particular scenario.

Comment: even I have been trying to do something very similar to this using components but I have JSON within each line or parts of JSON within each line which is confusing things. I will give your solution a try

Comment: Yes that worked! Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it .

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire is extensible, so I'd suggest writing your own response `ResponseSerializer` that can parse JSON by line. It seems that each line should parse fine, they're just not parseable together since the whole document isn't valid JSON.

Comment: how would I do that. I have never written a `ResponseSerializer `

Comment: I suggest you read [the documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#custom-response-serialization).